# Rails simple_form collection to %ul?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, collections, html-lists, simple-form

so I will get right into asking.

This is an input from my simple_form

```
= f.input :focus, collection: [[t('alg.focus.execution'), 'Execution'], [t('alg.focus.management'), 'Management'], [t('alg.focus.client'), 'Client'], [t('alg.focus.development'), 'Development']], :wrapper => :inline_checkbox, :include_blank => false, label: t('recruiter.jobs.new.focus')
```

and the output in html is this

```
<div class="select required job_focus">
<select class="select required" name="job[focus]" id="job_focus">          
<option value="Execution">Execuție</option>
<option value="Management">Management</option>
<option value="Client">Client</option>
<option value="Development">Dezvoltare</option></select></div>
```

Now what I want to do is to change the **select** tag into **ul** and **option** into **li**, this way I can customize the drop down menu as I want.

I have found a way in simple_form, that you can add a wrapper class to tag or to use another tag instead of other tags, but as I have seen is only limited to some tags like input, label, error etc. But I could not found how to change select and option.

by adding this element to the input `:wrapper => :inline_checkbox,`

and by adding this into simple_form.rb this

```
config.wrappers :inline_checkbox, :error_class => 'error' do |b|

  b.use :html5
  b.use :input
  b.use :label
  b.wrapper :tag => 'div', :class => 'controls' do |ba|
    ba.use :error, :wrap_with => { :tag => 'span', :class => 'help-inline' }
    ba.use :hint,  :wrap_with => { :tag => 'p', :class => 'help-block' }
  end
end
```

So I need your help.
Thank in advance.

Comment: Selects are hard to style. You are probably looking for  https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/Slashek/bootstrap-select-rails gem and simply add `selectpicker` class to the `input_html`.

An example such as

`<%= f.input :sharing_policy,
                    label: t('portal_new.privacy.share_designs'),
                    collection: sharing_policy_options,
                    selected: current_school[:sharing_policy],
                    include_blank: false,
                    include_hidden: false,
                    input_html: {class: 'selectpicker'}
        %>`